# Configuring Siri to tell me the things I want to know in the morning

Tags: siri, preferences

Is there a way for me to configure my MacBook or iPhone so that Siri will tell me my schedule for the day and other relevant information I want to know (like what the weather will be for the day) without having to ask multiple questions?

Ideally, I could just say "Siri, tell me the plan for the day" and she would respond with something like "You have a meeting from 2-3 and 4-4:15. It is going to be rainy today with highs in the upper 70s."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to iOS 12!

Once iOS 12 is released you will be able to use [Siri shortcuts](https://9to5mac.com/2018/06/05/ios-12-siri-shortcuts/) to add a phrase and have it do what you want for example.

"Good morning" could

- Greet you
- Tell you the weather
- Tell you your schedule for the day
- Send a good morning text to your family
- etc.

all just with "Good morning".

I will edit this answer to include the step by step to achieve exactly what you want to do as soon as iOS 12 is released.

iOS 12 is planned to be released early fall).

Comment: And this should be the same when Mojave releases for Mac, right?

Comment: @JackMoody Unfortunately, this feature won't be coming to Mojave. This is most likely because you can achieve just about anything without it. If you would like, open a new question and tag it with AppleScript. I will write a script for you.

Comment: [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334899/how-to-use-applescript-to-make-siri-shortcuts) is the link to the new question with the AppleScript question. I'm accepting this answer, because it answers my initial question of whether this is possible on iPhone and Mac.

Answer (score -4):

Not sure that Siri is a true 'assistant' like Alexa, etc. I've previously researched the query in the past...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Can you expand on this how specifically it answers the question? This seems like a really soft no. If you know that Siri can’t do this, let’s explain and document it.