# How to use AppleScript to make Siri shortcuts?

Tags: applescript, siri

Is there a way for me to configure my MacBook with AppleScript so that Siri will tell me my schedule for the day and other relevant information I want to know?

I would like to be able to write multiple commands into a single question like this:

Q: "Siri, what is new this morning"

A: "The weather is currently 70 degrees. The S&P 500 index is trading at $2800. You have 5 activities planned for the day..."

Essentially, I want to be able to have Siri answer a lot of questions she would normally answer by asking only one question.

Comment: Can you please list the all the different things that you want to occur?

Comment: What’s the weather? What is SPY trading at? What do I have on the calendar for today? What reminders do I have left to do?

Comment: K. Will create soon. Calendars may be bit difficult though. I will see what I can do.

Comment: Working on it. Looks like we would have to use a couple APIs. Will see what I can do but it may take awhile.

Comment: @JBis you don’t need to do all of this for me. If you can just point me to the information I can figure it out.

Comment: Are you sure? Your gonna need to know how to program.  I was gonna go with PHP and just parse the JSON from the APIs. Then run `php foobar.php` from AppleScript. We could add a trigger for it to run for "Siri, what is new this morning"

Comment: Its not too difficult an I would be happy to do it for you I just need some time.